# Laravel Auth: adding fields to "remeber" in login form

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

My `getCredentials()` method is using login, password and client_id

I moved it into my `authController`, modified and it works like a charm with one exception. When login fails my login form is only populated with previously used login (password is obviously empty) but client_id is missing.

I KNOW i can add it in `postLogin()` but I'd like to keep "vendor" part untouched.

What is the best practice here? Should I move also the whole `postLogin()` to my `authController` as well and change it there?

Comment: I have left, answer try see if it helps and let me know

Comment: Use `old('client_id', $clientId)` as the default value for the form field.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is to use `$remember`.

Regarding to Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#remembering-users), you need to add `$remember` like:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember))
{
    // The user is being remembered...
}
```

And in your blade add a check box like

```
<div>
    <input id="RememberMe" name="rememberme" type="checkbox"/>
    <label for="RememberMe">Remember Me</label>
</div>
```